# Git merge loses a few files

Tags: git

I have two git branch. One is "master" who has a lot of materials. The other one is called "simple". When I did originally cloned "Simple" from "Master", I removed a lot of files from Simple, so "Simple" is a stripped down version of "master". A couple weeks later, some amount of work has been done on "simple" and when i switch to the "master" branch and try

```
git merge simple
```

I notice that some of my codes, but not all of them (that were not in the "simple" branch) is currently missing. I have to do a reset to a pre-merged commitment to find all the files

Let me know what to do

Answer (score 2):

When Git performs a merge, it considers exactly three points: the two heads being merged (in this case, `simple` and `master`), and a third point, called the *merge base*, which is usually the common ancestor of those commits.

If you make a change on one branch between the merge base and that head, and you don't make a change on the other side, then that change will be included in the final merge.  In your case, the change is deleting a file, and the result has the file being deleted.  This is working as intended.

If you want to apply the changes from `simple` to `master` without including the deleted files, then you'll need to check out `simple` to another branch (`git checkout -b temp simple`) and do an interactive rebase (`git rebase -i master`), excluding the commits that removed the files.  Then, `temp` will be an extension of `master` with the relevant commits from `simple` applied on top.  You can then check out `master` and run `git merge temp` (either with `--ff-only` or `--no-ff`, depending on whether you want a merge commit) and then your changes will be incorporated into `master.

Comment: You could also revert the specific commits that deleted the files. This won't rewrite history.

Comment: this might be a stupid question, when i did ```git rebase -i master``` what exactly do i need to do after that? can i just try to rebase it to a particular commitment before all the files are deleted. i know the commitment number... The other thing is that when I branch out simple from master at the very beginning. I removed all the files and then now simple branch has more code than before and I am trying to merge with master

Comment: When the interactive editor comes up, delete the lines corresponding to the commits where you deleted files, then save and quit.  That will remove those commits and their deletions from the history of the branch you're working on.  The goal is to create a temporary branch based off of simple that doesn't contain the deletions and then merge that.

Answer (score 1):

If all of the commits on `simple` that you wish to merge into `master` happened after the commits that deleted the files on branch `simple`, (and from your description it sounds as if that is true), then there is a *simple* solution:

Use `git log simple` to determine the last commit ID that contains the deletes that you do not wish to occur on branch `master`. Let's call that commit ID `abcd1234`.

Now, checkout `master` and perform the following two merges in this order:

```
git switch master
git merge --strategy=ours abcd1234 -m "Merge branch simple without deleting files"
git merge simple
```

The first merge command tells Git to bring in all the commit IDs on `simple` up through `X`, but without taking any of those changes. The second merge will merge in the rest of the commits on `simple` which have the actual changes you wish to bring into `master`.